# Buttons that update labels in a grid for each respective row

Tags: python, python-3.x, pyqt, pyqt4

I have a QGrid with 2 columns and 3 rows. The first column consists of QPushButtons's and the second column consists of QLabel's.
The buttons => ["This Button", "That Button", "A Button"]. All the labels start at the text 0. Pressing the button in a row should change the text (number) of the label in that same row by adding 1.

The above is a simplified version of the problem, where in reality I have 10+ rows, and 5+ columns.

How would I create all of these rows and columns in a grid with as little code as possible? And how would I link each button to it's respective label without having to create a function for each separate button?

Comment: You can create all these row by starting writing some line of code first. It is very simple.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are several ways to solve it, I will show some:

1. lambda functios:

---

```
class Widget(QWidget):
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        QWidget.__init__(self, *args, **kwargs)
        lay = QGridLayout(self)
        for i in range(3):
            btn = QPushButton("button-{}".format(i), self)
            lbl = QLabel("{}".format(0))
            lay.addWidget(btn, i, 0)
            lay.addWidget(lbl, i, 1)
            btn.clicked.connect(lambda checked, l=lbl: self.fun(l))

    def fun(self, lbl):
        n = int(lbl.text()) + 1
        lbl.setText(str(n))
```

2. dictionary

---

```
class Widget(QWidget):
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        QWidget.__init__(self, *args, **kwargs)
        lay = QGridLayout(self)
        self.connections = {}
        for i in range(3):
            btn = QPushButton("button-{}".format(i), self)
            lbl = QLabel("{}".format(0))
            lay.addWidget(btn, i, 0)
            lay.addWidget(lbl, i, 1)
            self.connections[btn] = lbl
            btn.clicked.connect(self.fun)

    def fun(self):
        lbl = self.connections[self.sender()]
        n = int(lbl.text()) + 1
        lbl.setText(str(n))
```

Comment: Thank you for the help! Really smart solutions!